# How can I get a notification when a drive enters standby, using UDEV?

Tags: raspberry-pi, hard-disk, udev

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with OS Lite and some disk drives attached to its USB ports. I also have a Python script that I want to be executed when the drives enter and exit the standby mode. I made a file named "99-hdd-standby.rules" in the "/etc/udev/rules.d" and added to it:

```
ACTION=="change", DEVNAME=="*/sd[a-z]", ATTR{state}=="active/idle", RUN+="/usr/bin/python3 /home/marus/hdd_power.py act %k"
ACTION=="change", DEVNAME=="*/sd[a-z]", ATTR{state}=="standby", RUN+="/usr/bin/python3 /home/marus/hdd_power.py stb %k"
```

I saved the file and restarted the udev service. But my Python script is not executed when the HDD enter and exist from standby. The script doesn't have errors. If I execute it manualy I get the notification.

Then I tried with this simple rule just to see if it works:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/bin/echo 'USB device state changed' >> /home/marus/udev_log.txt"
```

It should write to a file when a USB device is connected or disconnected. But it didn't work too...

What is wrong that I can't make any rule to be triggered ?

**Update:**

I tried with this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/trigger.sh"
```

...and indeed, the script is executed when I connect and disconect a hard drive. And this is confirmed by the `udevadm monitor` too. But when I put a drive in standby, no event is triggered in udevadm monitor. So, I gues that is not possible to get notified when a drive enter the standby mode... with udev.

If you have any others idea, please let me know.